# Getting deeplinking data from install referrer intent

Tags: android, intentfilter, deep-linking

I want this flow for my app.
when user clicks on link of my website containing deep linking elements eg: `www.example.com/lorem?a=qwerty&b=poiuyt` two of the following things may happen:

1. If app is present then user will be taken to respective activity and content is shown (This I accomplished by using following)

   `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="http" />
   <data android:scheme="https" />
   <data android:host="www.example.com" />`
2. If app is not present in device, then user must be taken to the app store, if user downloads and runs the app then this content page should open. (THIS I AM NOT ABLE TO DO)

Answer (score 0):

arrow001,

Deep linking with Android can be tricky. Your problem of being able to deep link to people who don't have your app installed (i.e. if no app -> go to app store -> pass data through install -> load deep linked content) is easy to accomplish with Branch's open source Android SDK. It will let you pass data through install and your generated links will work cross platform (desktop/android/ios).

Here are a few links to get you started:

Get to know what Branch does (i.e. how it solves your problem):
https://dev.branch.io/#what-does-branch-do

Adding the SDK to your project:
https://dev.branch.io/recipes/add_the_sdk/android

Setting up deep linking & generating deep links:
https://dev.branch.io/recipes/setup_deep_linking/android

SDK Source:
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Android-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK

Sample app:
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-Example-Deep-Linking-Branchster-Android